# Использование обработчиков бота, по умолчанию, асинхронно (run_async=True)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-telegram-bot

В библиотеке [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot) обработка запросов, по умолчанию, выполняется последовательно.

Для параллельной работы использовался декоратор `@run_async`, который во все функции-обработчики нужно было добавлять, пример:

```
import threading

from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Updater, MessageHandler, Filters, CallbackContext
from telegram.ext.dispatcher import run_async

@run_async
def on_request(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    message = update.effective_message
    message.reply_text(f'Thread: {threading.current_thread()}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    updater = Updater(TOKEN)

    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, on_request))

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()
```

Но с версии **13**, декоратор устарел и вместо него библиотека предлагает использовать одноименный параметр в обработчиках `Handler` или запускать функции через метод `Dispatcher.run_async` (что немного не то):

```
TelegramDeprecationWarning: The @run_async decorator is deprecated. Use the `run_async` parameter of your Handler or `Dispatcher.run_async` instead.
  return self.callback(update, context)
```

Использование параметра `run_async=True` работает:

```
import threading

from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Updater, MessageHandler, Filters, CallbackContext

def on_request(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    message = update.effective_message
    message.reply_text(f'Thread: {threading.current_thread()}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    updater = Updater(TOKEN)

    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, on_request, run_async=True))

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()
```

#### Но возникла проблема перехода на параметр `run_async=True` вместо декоратора `@run_async`

Ведь нужно сделать следующие вещи во всех поддерживаемых ботах:

1. Убрать импорт декоратора `from telegram.ext.dispatcher import run_async`
2. Убрать декоратор `@run_async` во всех функциях-обработчиках
3. Всем обработчикам указать параметр `run_async=True`

   - Кстати, это касается и метода добавления обработчика ошибок [Dispatcher.add_error_handler](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.dispatcher.html#telegram.ext.Dispatcher.add_error_handler)

Есть боты, у которых обработчиков может быть ~50. Труднозатратно каждому обработчику указывать тот параметр. Конечно, можно оставить старую версию, но если хочется обновить версию, то что можно тут сделать?

#### Как менее болезненно перейти на асинхронный режим работы бота?

---

**PS.**

Понять работает функция-обработчик в отдельном потоке можно по названию потока, что вернется от бота при `f'Thread: {threading.current_thread()}'`.

Вот это без потоков:

```
Thread: <Thread(Bot:{id бота}:dispatcher, started 772)>
```

А этот в потоке:

```
Thread: <Thread(Bot:{id бота}:worker:a36abf98-33a8-4c73-8c02-51a3e5241b5e_0, started 26488)>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первое, что пришло в голову это пройтись по всем обработчикам и принудительно указать им `run_async = True`:

```
...

for commands in dp.handlers.values():
    for command in commands:
        command.run_async = True

updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```

**Это работает**

#### Но такое решение костыльное, есть способ лучше

В библиотеке есть класс [Defaults](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.defaults.html) (по-моему, он появился как раз с 13 версии), у этого класса есть поле `run_async` и объект класса можно передавать в настройки бота.

Помимо того, что использование [Defaults](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.defaults.html) является официальным API, это еще влияет на значения по-умолчанию, например, если в каких-то случаях **не** нужно обработки асинхронно, то можно указать это в обработчике и это не поменяется при установке `Defaults(run_async=True)`, в отличии от способа выше:

```
MessageHandler(Filters.text, on_request, run_async=False),
```

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/5268034025c70f0ef3b9c09d5e062f76e15e2d19/telegram_bot_examples/set_run_async=True_for_all_handlers__using_defaults__simple.py#L28)

```
import threading

from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Updater, MessageHandler, Filters, CallbackContext
from telegram.ext.defaults import Defaults

def on_request(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    message = update.effective_message
    message.reply_text(f'Thread: {threading.current_thread()}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    updater = Updater(
        TOKEN,
        defaults=Defaults(run_async=True),
    )

    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, on_request))

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()
```