# Как использовать многопоточность в телеграм боте на python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot

Создал телеграм бота, он работает на одном потоке, можно ли как-то переключить его в многопоточный режим

Comment: Уточните какую библиотеку используете. Если python-telegram-bot, то там нужно указать асинхронную работу через `defaults=Defaults(run_async=True)`: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1335826/201445, либо каждому обработчику явно указывать `run_async=True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте использовать
Threading.Thread(do_work), где do_work - ваша функция, которую вы хотите запустить в многопоточном режиме.

`import threading
thread = threading.Thread(do_work)
thread.start()`